[Trace32]Communication failed
After installing T32 with open zip file, I can't open Trace32 as you see the picture below.
'ini file' path is corrected to the installed T32 path.
After executing the TRACE32, I see this picture.
Is there any log file that I can look up for this issue?

I see this image, after clicking startup.cmm.
Plus,


I am pretty sure, all you need to do is to connect your powered PowerDebug to your PC via USB before starting the software.
